# Kotlin by lazy throws NullPointerException

Tags: kotlin, exception, nullpointerexception, null

I am currently trying to learn Kotlin with the help of the book "Kotlin Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" and so far everything worked.
But now I am struggling with the "lazy" initialization which throws a NullPointerException which says

> Cannot invoke "kotlin.Lazy.getValue()" because "< local1>" is null

The corresponding lines are:

```
val hometown by lazy { selectHometown() } 
private fun selectHometown(): String = File("data/towns.txt").readText().split("\n").shuffled().first()
```

In case you want to compile it yourself or need more code for a better understanding I provide the Game.kt and Player.kt down below. If "lazy" is dropped for a "normal" initialization the hometown gets assigned as intended.
Any tips for solving the problem and understanding the cause of it is welcome.

```
// Game.kt
package com.bignerdranch.nyethack

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val player = Player("Madrigal")
    player.castFireball()
}

private fun printPlayerStatus(player: Player) {
    println("(Aura: ${player.auraColor()}) " + "(Blessed: ${if (player.isBlessed) "YES" else "NO"})")
    println("${player.name} ${player.formatHealthStatus()}")
}
```

```
// Player.kt
package com.bignerdranch.nyethack

import java.io.File

class Player(_name: String, var healthPoints: Int = 100, val isBlessed: Boolean, private val isImmortal: Boolean) {


    var name = _name
        get() = "${field.capitalize()} of $hometown"
        private set(value) {
            field = value.trim()
        }

    constructor(name: String) : this(name, isBlessed = true, isImmortal = false) {
        if (name.toLowerCase() == "kar") healthPoints = 40
    }

    init {
        require(healthPoints > 0, { "healthPoints must be greater than zero." })
        require(name.isNotBlank(), { "Player must have a name" })
    }

    val hometown by lazy { selectHometown() }

    private fun selectHometown(): String = File("data/towns.txt").readText().split("\n").shuffled().first()

    fun castFireball(numFireballs: Int = 2) =
        println("A glass of Fireball springs into existence. (x$numFireballs)")


    fun auraColor(): String {
        val auraVisible = isBlessed && healthPoints > 60 || isImmortal
        return if (auraVisible) "GREEN" else "NONE"
    }
    fun formatHealthStatus() =
        when (healthPoints) {
            100 -> "is an excellent condition!"
            in 90..99 -> "has a few scratches."
            in 75..89 -> if (isBlessed) {
                "has some minor wounds but is healing quite quickly"
            } else {
                "has some minor wounds"
            }
            in 15..74 -> "looks pretty hurt"
            else -> "is in awful condition!"
        }

}
```

I forgot the towns.txt so here it is (not that it matters much)

```
Neversummer
Abelhaven
Phandoril
Tampa
Sanorith
Trell
Zan'tro
Hermi Hermi
Curlthistle Forest
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When something like this happens, it's usually due to bad ordering of initialization.

The initialization of the `Player` class goes this way:

1. the `name` property has its backing field initialized with the `_name` value
2. the `init` block is run, and tries to access `name`
3. the getter of `name` tries to read the `hometown` property, but fails because `hometown` is still not initialized
4. ...if things had gone right, the `hometown` property would be initialized now with the lazy delegate

So basically you're trying to access `hometown` before the lazy delegate is configured.
If you move `hometown`'s declaration above the `init` block, you should be fine.

You can see the fix in action [on the playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: I will try your suggestion as soon as I'm back home. But won't init be executed right after the construction no matter where the code ist placed inside the class?

Comment: No. Property initializers and `init` blocks are run in a top-down order. Any constructor _body_ runs **after** all properties and `init` blocks (whereas constructor _arguments_ are evaluated **before** properties/init).

Comment: Cause confirmed.  (I identified the problem just before you posted this :-)  @Tignite It would be a good exercise for you (as well as saving all your readers trouble) to create a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example); doing so would show you where the problem is and what you need to trigger it.  (I got it down to about 10 non-blank lines of code.)

Comment: @Tignite you can read more about the intricacies of class initialization order here: https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/an-in-depth-look-at-kotlins-initializers-a0420fcbf546

Comment: Usually I would have done that, but I had only little time left to catch my train before posting. @gidds I think I have to compare my code to your explanation to fully comprehend it but it seems like it will help me understand initialization a little bit better, thanks Ben P.

Comment: @gidds I actually tested the fix on play.kotlinlang.org before posting :) The reason I was not 100% sure is because on the playground the file access fails for security reasons :D Now I replaced with a dumb string, and I confirm it works